# Make library functions use a class derived from a library class

Tags: c++, dll, polymorphism, vtable

I have a .dll which I can build myself. I have a class, `Lion`, derived from a class in the library, `Cat`, which overrides a virtual function, `Leap()`. I want to create an object of type `Lion`, pass it to library functions which expect a type of `Cat`, such that when they make calls to `Cat->Leap()`, they use the overidden virtual function, `Lion->Leap()`.

Is this at all possible?

Everything I've tried so far has ended up with the overridden function being ignored. I'm guessing that this is because when the library is compiled it works out how to resolve calls to `Leap()`, at which point my derived type doesn't exist. Alternatively, because the library refers to an object of type `Cat` (which is actually of type `Lion`), it calls `Cat::Leap()`, rather than `Lion::Leap()`.

I had thought that the fact the the function was virtual would mean that, even though it was being called from within the library, it would resolve the call by looking at the vtable for the object at run-time, which would be for the derived type.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the function prototypes for the library functions you want to call.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, the library needs to be written a certain way: it should take its `Cat`s by reference or by pointer, and not by value (which is, unfortunately, the default way the parameters are passed in C++). If you pass a `Lion` to a function that expects a `Cat` by value, the `Lion` gets [*sliced*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) to a `Cat`, and effectively becomes a `Cat` as far as the function is concerned.

Comment: Slicing Lions is dangerous, don't try this at home. No Animals Were Harmed® to produce this answer.

Comment: Haha, nice comment... you beat me, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual functions enable dynamic / late binding which is determined at run-time.  So, you wouldn't have to worry about a compile time decision impacting your code like this.

As long as a function is virtual in the base class, it is overridden in your derived class, and your library function calls through a const-reference or pointer, it will work fine regardless of where the classes are defined.

Chances are you're slicing your object and ending up with just the base class half because you're passing by value instead of by pointer or reference.

Think of it like this:

**If I pass a lion in as a cat, by value, it will make a copy of the "cat" that the lion was casted in to.  That copy will be used, but the copy was only of the cat half, so it can't possibly dispatch to the lion half - it doesn't exist in the copy.  Those functions and data members simply aren't present in it.  Passing by reference or pointer ensures you still have the whole original lion object available.**

Answer (score 0):

in the library's header file declare a virtual leap:

```
class Cat {
public:
  virtual void leap() const { /* ... */ };
  /// ...
};
```

and use `Cat`s by passing references or pointers in the library source code:

```
void LibraryUsesCat(const Cat*c)
{ c-> leap(); }
```

In your applications override the virtual function:

```
class Lion : public Cat {
public:
  void leap() const { /* ... */ }
  /// ...
};
```

and this should just work.